# Base64 Encode Image and Save it later to a file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, image-processing, base64

I have an application where an admin can upload an image. I save the image in a file and also base64 encode (using Base64.strict_encode method of ruby) & save in my DB. This is so that when later someone deleted the physical file from the HDD/Server, I can still generate it back by base64 decoding it (Base64.decode method) and save in a file.

But the encoding and decoding didn't go well as the image get damaged and I'm unable to view it after save.

I checked the output of the Base64.strict_encode against the result when I used http://www.base64-image.de/ to encode the file, they were different.

Can anyone help me with this? What am I doing wrong? What am I not doing?

ENCODING THE IMAGE DURING UPLOAD:

```
  imageLoc = image.image.to_s
  logger.info '>>>>>>' + (Base64.strict_encode64(open(imageLoc).read)).to_s
  image_data = Base64.strict_encode64(File.open(imageLoc, 'rb').read)
  CategoryImage.update_image_data(image.id,image_data)
```

DECODING WHEN IMAGE FILE IS LOST:

```
File.open(File.join(APP_CONFIG['image_storage_location'], image[:image]), 'wb') { |f|
    content = image[:image_data]
    content.gsub!('\\r', "\r")
    content.gsub!('\\n', "\n")
    f.write(Base64.decode64(content))
    f.close
  }
```

ENCODED IMAGE FROM THE SITE (base64-image.de): https://shrib.com/cYLKfEe1?v=nc

ENCODED IMAGE FROM MY CODE: https://shrib.com/CODE-encoded%20image?v=nc

**EDIT**

When I replaced the encoded image data in my DB with the one I generated from the above named website, my image was regenerated and viewable. So the real is with the encoding.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Had once a similar issue, solved it by replacing the File.read method with IO.binread(imageLoc). Hope it helps. :)

Comment: I was putting the code in the wrong file before... Thanks. You saved my day!